# Junit Test for Exception in a @InjectMocks class

Tags: java, spring, exception, junit, mockito

I have the following code in my application.

Can someone please help me with writing a test case for this.

**Service.java**

````
```public class Service{
public void createMessage(){
try{
LOG.info("message sent");
}catch(JAXBException){
LOG.info("exception occured");
}
}```
````

**ServiceTest.java**

````
```public class ServiceTest{
@InjectMocks
Service service;

@Test
public void testCreateMessageException(){
doThrow(JAXBException.class).when(service.createMessage));
}```
````

I tried the above test case but it is giving me the below error.
*org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);*

Comment: First of all , the test is incorrect. 1) The `Service.createMessage()` will not throw `JAXBException` as it is already handled within the method call. 2) `when()` is not applicable to methods with `void` return type 3) `service.createMessage` in the code shared is not a method call 4) usage of `when()` is incorrect 5) Use `@Mock` instead of `@InjectMocks` , later is for a different purpose. Please share the actual code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your understanding is correct you cannot use when().then() on the service which is annotated with @InjectMocks ( the system under test). it has to be used on the service which is Autowired in the system under test.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is a very common mistake when using doThrow().when().
So you wrote:

```
doThrow(JAXBException.class).when(service.createMessage());
```

that should be:

```
doThrow(JAXBException.class).when(service).createMessage();
```